# Is my code forking?

Tags: javascript, html

```
 function loopthrough (i) {
            i++;
            if (i <= 20) {

                play_multi_sound("aud"+i);
                $("#debug").html(i);
                setTimeout("loopthrough("+i+");",242); }
            else {
                loops++;
                $("#debug").html("rest");
                $("#loops").html(loops);
                setTimeout("loopthrough("+0+");",1000);
            }
        }
```

Does my code look like it is forking? since after about 3 loops it is litrally crashing the browser. I am using excessive HTML5 audio since I like to test new features and whilst im still a newbie at Javascript I really need this code to work. (Im making a simple beat game in canvas where you use a pong style paddle and each ball you hit of varying speed it will play a sound, thus making a cool beat)... Atm im just testing the capabilities of alot of audio being looped through at once.

So yeah my basic question is "Is my code efficient, is it forking and is there anyway of improving this greatly if you know of a better way?"

Thanks,
Tom C.

EDIT:

Just removed my loops++; (for some reason it was returning NaN even though it was defined as global) and it actually successfully looped 20 times without flaws.

Comment: What is the need for `var i = i + 1;` and not `i = i + 1`? Way to initialise values if null? (Haven't used javascript in a while)

Comment: Best bet is to try and do a bit of debugging - add console.log("bla") in there and see how many times it comes up. That should let you know if it's working properly or not and help you find out where it's crashing.

Comment: The less timeouts you have, the better. Maybe you can abort some?

Comment: Ok I have no clue how to get the console up in FF Beta 8. Also Blam, I thought I had to use var if its 0. Not too sure but I wanted to be on the safe side.

Comment: FireBug extension for FireFox?

Comment: Doesnt work properly on beta 8 :( Firebug that is... Gosh these comments go fast
!

Comment: won't fix the problem, but you should do `i++;` instead of `var i ) i + 1;`.

Comment: **@Tom C**; `loops++` also, if you haven't already.

Comment: Does anybody know what "forking" is supposed to mean?

Comment: Added that in with the i++ hehe

Comment: Well, yeah, it's looping.. loopthrough(i) calls setTimeout(loopthrough(i)) which calls setTimeout(loopthrough(i)) which calls setTimeout(loopthrough))..... Repeat until infinity.

Comment: What is `play_multi_sound` doing? Creating a new audio element? The whole audio thing is buggy as hell. I've experienced Opera, Chrome and Firefox crashing when playing sound in quick succession (not to mention them throwing a trillion errors in the command line)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: pointy somthing that selfreferences more than once at the same time thus "forking" out into loads of itself I think?

Comment: The self referencing is what I intended however Im not sure if its spliting off because of some sort of delay thus causing it to start forking out? @Ivo Wetzel the play multi sound is a function I found on the net to allow you to simultaneusly play up to 10 audio elements.

Comment: Well you're doing it every .2 seconds... If the first call doesn't finish in .2 seconds (memory, lag, whatever) you'll start growing the calls, which will cause the system to slow, causing the function to execute even slower. Just add another 0 to your timeout and see if it sorts itself

Comment: @Tom If firebug doesn't work in beta 8, then maybe try it in Chrome or older version of Firefox (just for the debugging). As far as the forking, it doesn't look like it would be forking, but you never know.

Comment: However mind you, inf loops are NEVER the right solution, not even when building fractals...

Comment: When I start to actually build it, I wont be using inf loops but Im thinking the game should be quite fast paced therefore I wanted to test it under like "perfect"(if a player gets it 100%) conditions. So it isnt an issue with my code rather an issue with the audio being quite buggy? I have an example here 90.197.69.23/nuke/audio.php

Comment: Why not just use a FOR loop instead? This just seems to be a rather unconventional way of looping through 20 iterations and then repeateing?

Comment: @Meke because I dont want to put the timers going all at once, this way it plays it, then proccesses the next one does it not?

Comment: Well, assuming it finishes in the time you give it. Which, as said, isn't ensured if you run into any sort of lag. Either way, I'm not a fan of the setup, which isn't to say you're wrong, just that you might be better off with a simpler solution (occam). But in the end, it's your code. Run it with Firebug and test it out. That's the *right* way to do it ;)

Comment: Btw - A bit of help, I ran your link above through a slow computer, the counter works but the sound plays randomly, usually at 13 and Sometimes in the end or beginning..

Comment: I'll keep logging it for a bit and stress the system, but so far, there aren't any issues.

Comment: Yeah I think the loop that I used isnt that great since well, it doesnt loop so it creates a random noise (I think my server just crashed :( Its only wamp! Dont all connect :P)

Comment: Back again - The sound is changing after a bit of stress and now only one sounds plays.. The short tick tick tick sound..

Comment: The sound is now all gone, the loop still ticks tho'..

Comment: ah, yeah I assume thats html5 audio just messing up :( Do you know of any other way other than flash to play a sound like this? (am I allowed to sorta change my question) - Then again that does defeat the object of me using HTML5

Comment: Further note: Your page chewed up 15% of my CPU...

Comment: You can just edit your question. :)

Comment: Hmm since it should only ever play 1 audio file for each step does that mean it stacks the CPU sorta thing as it goes along? or does 1 audio element cause the whole of that CPU usage?... I might totally remove that channels thing as im sure that could be causing a bit of lag (and Ive realised I dont need more than one channel anyway)

Comment: Why don't you use audio events instead of `setTimeout`? I.e. start playing the next sound when the previous sound's `ended` event fires.

Comment: that sounds like a good idea, I didnt realise such events existed, checking them out now (and trying to get my server to work again :()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did some tests, and I am sticking it here so that the code is clear.

```
function loopthrough (i) {
  i++;
  if (i <= 20) {
    console.log("bla");
    setTimeout(function(){ loopthrough(i); }, 242); }
  else {
    console.log("lala");
    setTimeout(function(){ loopthrough(0); }, 1000);
  }
}

loopthrough(0);
```

That worked fine and it never crashed. And it didn't fork either.

So, it's crashing on something else.

I would try this in another browser as well, and see if it crashes - could just be the FF beta 8 crashing.

Try removing 1 bit at a time from it and see if it starts to work - it's a good way to narrow down the culprit.

I bet it's the audio that's crashing it...

*** update ***

Try bumping up the timeout delay - it could be that the audio doesn't finish and then attempts to play again and is somehow backlogging.

Comment: Quick, get rid of eval before I work on getting my reputation back down to a nice round number...

Comment: @Ivo Not sure what you mean - what eval?

Comment: @xil3 There you go. setTimeout with a string as its arguments uses eval under the hood.

Comment: Umm why the hell did you down vote me? I'm just trying to help. This community is turning into a joke...

Comment: That was a copy and paste from what he had, and that wasn't the problem we were trying to deal with either.

Comment: So, the OP does something wrong and you just decide not to tell him? Sure, **that** is the joke.

Comment: heyhey people lets not start an argument D:... eval thingy noted in brain :), Thanks (and thanks to xil3 for the advice).

Comment: @xil3 We don't usually do that - changing the meaning of answers is a big no-no, and usually creates more problems than it solves

Comment: @xil3 Copy and pasting without pointing out all errors, that's a joke.

Comment: Raynos please dont downvote him on an error on my behalf D: (Sorry xil3)

Comment: @xil3 : Don't be that angry, I didn't downvoted you, so don't blame me. Still, instead of arguing, you have a nice feature on answers on SO : `edit`. Edit your answer w/o the _`eval` under the hood_ and I bet downvoters will cancel their votes.

Comment: I just edited it, and if you notice another error, please do let me know.

Comment: @xil3 `setTimeout` takes a function as its first argument, `loopthrough(0)` will execute the `loopthrough` function and use **that** return value (which is most likely `undefined` since I hardly doubt that `looptrhough` returns anything) as the first argument for `setTimeout`. You need to pass in an anonymous function which calls `loopthrough`. `setTimeout(function(){   loopthrough(0); }, 1000)` fix it and I'll remove my down vote.